# Limit input tags to a certain number

Tags: jquery

I want to limit the number of `<input>` tags to ten when Im adding it through Jquery. How do i go abt this? Here's my javascript code as a `<script>` tag

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(window).load(function () {
     $(function () {
             var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
             var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
             $('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
                     $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20"name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                     i++;
                     return false;
                 });
             $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
                     if (i > 2) {
                         $(this).parents('p').remove();
                         i--;
                     }
                     return false;
                 });
         });
 });
 </script>
```

Here's the **formatted** HTML

```
<a href="#"
    id="addScnt"
    name="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a>

 <div id="p_scents">
    <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
 </div>
```

Comment: my eyes..... code format, phrase construction, explainations, fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to hold the number of elements you have created and whenever you create one increment it with one. You can then check against this variable whether you have reached the limit or not.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be work.

```
$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {

if(i >= 10) alert("can not add anymore"); return false;

 $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20"name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
 i++;

 return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check how many inputs are there and deem whether or not they should be added. Also, a couple of things I noticed.. `.live()` is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery (replaced with `.on()`) and your ID's are repeating. Lets fix that:

```
$(document).on('click', '#addScnt', function() {
    var inputCount = $(".p_scnt_add").length;

    if (inputCount <= 10) {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="p_scnt_add" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
    }
    return false;
});
```

I changed your repeating ID's to use classes instead.